# Tellg and seekg and file read not working

Tags: c++, file, binary

I am Trying to read 64000 bytes from file in binary mode in buffer at one time till end of the file. My problem is tellg() returns position in hexadecimal value, How do I make it return decimal value?
 because my if conditions are not working, it is reading more than 64000 and when I am relocating my pos and size_stream(size_stream = size_stream - 63999;
pos = pos + 63999;), it is pointing to wrong positions each time.

How do I read 64000 bytes from file into buffer in binary mode at once till the end of file?

Any help would be appreciated

```
  std::fstream fin(file, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (fin.good())
    {
        fin.seekg(0, fin.end);
        int size_stream = (unsigned int)fin.tellg(); fin.seekg(0, fin.beg);
        int pos = (unsigned int)fin.tellg();
        //........................<sending the file in blocks  
        while (true)
        {
            if (size_stream > 64000)
            {
                fin.read(buf, 63999);
                buf[64000] = '\0';
                CString strText(buf);
                SendFileContent(userKey,
                    (LPCTSTR)strText);
                size_stream = size_stream - 63999;
                pos = pos + 63999;
                fin.seekg(pos, std::ios::beg);
            }
            else
            {
                fin.read(buf, size_stream);
                buf[size_stream] = '\0';
                CString strText(buf);
                SendFileContent(userKey,
                    (LPCTSTR)strText); break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *My problem is `tellg()` returns position in hexadecimal value,* That does not make sense. `tellg()` returns an integral value. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Why do you need to seek at all? Keep reading until you reach the end.

Comment: I wanted to send file in chunks of 64000 bytes..so I wanted to seek

Comment: You don't need to seek for that. Read 64000 bytes, send the bytes, read 64000 bytes, send the bytes, and so on.  Don't read more than you need.

Comment: 1st time I will read 1st chunk of 64000 bytes into buffer.....next time I should read next chunk of 64000 bytes(not from starting of file)..how would I do that..any help would be great

Comment: You simply ask the stream to read 64000 bytes, then ask it to read 64000 bytes again, and again, and again.  The file position will advance automatically during each read.  Stop reading from the stream when a read fails, either because EOF was reached or an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is tellg() returns position in hexadecimal value

No, it doesn't.  It returns an integer value.  You can *display* the value in hex, but it is not *returned* in hex.

> when I am relocating my pos and size_stream(size_stream = size_stream - 63999; pos = pos + 63999;), it is pointing to wrong positions each time.

You shouldn't be seeking in the first place.  After performing a read, leave the file position where it is.  The next read will pick up where the previous read left off.

> How do I read 64000 bytes from file into buffer in binary mode at once till the end of file?

Do something more like this instead:

```
std::ifstream fin(file, std::ios::binary);
if (fin)
{
    unsigned char buf[64000];
    std::streamsize numRead;
    do
    {
        numRead = fin.readsome(buf, 64000);
        if ((!fin) || (numRead < 1)) break;

        // DO NOT send binary data using `LPTSTR` string conversions.
        // Binary data needs to be sent *as-is* instead.
        //
        SendFileContent(userKey, buf, numRead);
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Or this:

```
std::ifstream fin(file, std::ios::binary);
if (fin)
{
    unsigned char buf[64000];
    std::streamsize numRead;
    do
    {
        if (!fin.read(buf, 64000))
        {
            if (!fin.eof()) break;
        }
        numRead = fin.gcount();
        if (numRead < 1) break;

        // DO NOT send binary data using `LPTSTR` string conversions.
        // Binary data needs to be sent *as-is* instead.
        //
        SendFileContent(userKey, buf, numRead);
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Comment: Hi when ever, I am trying to read the file using above logic..readsome is not reading even a single character and streamsize is always zero